# Add new elements based on position and rotation angle of main element

Tags: javascript, rotation

I'm building a game in vanilla javascript where you can spot fishes on a radar. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

**I want objects (fish) to show up randomly on the position of the dial (randomly on the width/height) while its spinning.** I am able to get the angle of the dial, and the position, but I have no idea how to calculate the position of the new objects.

My current ugly solution involves creating a temporary div *inside* the dial, get the position, and use those for the new object, but it doesn't really work properly.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2x6cw841/5/) for what I have so far

```
function createNewFish() {

// Create new fishies

/*
const pos = document.getElementById('dial').getBoundingClientRect();
const degrees = getDialDegrees();

console.log(pos)
console.log(degrees)

// Calculate position for fish?
*/
```

Comment: You may use canvas or SVG.

Comment: Not an answer: If you don't want to do this with divs, I suggest looking into HTML5 Canvas. Much more elegant solutions to Vanilla JS game development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone attempting to do the same, I've managed to solve it using the following solution:

When you have a dial that spins, you can fill the dial with some equal divs (I used 9) like so:

```
function DialGenerator() {
  for(let i=0;i<9;i++) {
    const insideDial = document.createElement('div');
    insideDial.classList.add('dial-inside')
    insideDial.setAttribute('id', 'dial-inside-'+i)
    document.getElementById('dial').appendChild(insideDial)
  }
}
```

Then if you want to show elements on random positions *on* the dial (like my radar needs), you can just get a random div inside the dial using **Math.random()** and get the position of this div:

```
function getPosition() {
    const n = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
    // Get a random position on the dial for the fish to appear on
    const dialPosition = document.getElementById('dial-inside-'+n).getBoundingClientRect();
    return {'top':dialPosition.top, 'left':dialPosition.left}
 }
```

This returns the position of the div on the dial, which you can use to place your elements on the radar.

Hope this helps someone!